# How to access mongoose data : Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am getting data like this:

This is the code :

```
User.find({ Username: user }, function(err, found_user) {

                    console.log('user data'+ found_user );

                    if(found_user.length > 0){

                        console.log('inside found user');
                        var recordings = found_user.recordings;
                        console.log(recordings)
                        for (var singleRecords in recordings){
                            console.log("Single record :"+singleRecords);
                            if(!singleRecords.isPlayed){
                                console.log(singleRecords.playingUrl);
                                twiml.play(singleRecords.playingUrl);
                                found_user.recordings[singleRecords].isPlayed = true;
                                found_user.save(function (err) {
                                    if(err)
                                        throw err
                                });


                            }
                        }
                    }
```

And this is the value of found User :

```
user data   { Username: 'B',
     __v: 2,
     _id: 58ac15e4b4e1232f6f118ba3,
     recordings:
      [ { isPlayed: false,
          playingUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/public/toplay/playing_file_1487672817599.mp3' },
        { isPlayed: false,
              playingUrl: 'http://localhost:8000/public/toplay/playing_file_1487672827411.mp3' } ] 
        }
inside found user
```

in variable found_user. But it is not giving me any data inside it. Like found_user.Username gives undefined value.
I want to store that recordings array inside a variable. Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: please show us the code which you are trying ?

Comment: first log found_user using `console.log(found_user);` and show us the output

Comment: @nivas please see updated ques

Comment: @RohailNajam please see updated ques

Comment: Post all of the output from console.log

Comment: `found_user` is an array. Use `findOne` instead i.e. `User.findOne({ Username: user }).exec(function(err, found_user) { ... })`

Comment: @chridam thanks. by replacing find with findOne it works. Please write a proper answer so that i can mark that as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)** returns an array of docs that match the criteria in the callback hence the line

```
var recordings = found_user.recordings;
```

will not work as it's expecting a Document not an array.

You could use **[`findOne()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)** method which returns a document as:

```
User.findOne({ Username: user }.exec(function(err, found_user) {    
    console.log('user data'+ found_user );
    if (found_user) {
        console.log('inside found user');
        var recordings = found_user.recordings;
        console.log(recordings);
    }
});
```